# how to stop Subscribe?

Tags: meteor

I have two selects where the seconds values depends on the choosen value in the first one (Countrys / States) both are collections

When i subscribe with for example Belgian as country i get the states for Belgian
But when i choose another country (ex. Netherlands) the states are added !

I read that i must stop de subscription with .stop() an renew the subscription but this doesnt deems to work ???

My code :

```
 'click #stateList' : function(event, template) {
    var x = myTrim($("#countryList").val());
    var y = Countrys.findOne({country: x});
    var z = y.nr;
    if(this.stateSub != null){
        this.stateSub.stop();
    }
    this.stateSub = Meteor.subscribe('stateList', z);

}
```

It seems that this.stateSub is always undefined even if there is already a working subscribe ???

What am i doing wrong ???

thanks

Comment: Have you tried binding it to your `template` object instead? Like `template.stateSub`?

Answer (score 0):

In template events, `this` binds to the context document (in impressive ways sometimes) so you can get `this._id` for the document in the "HTML scope" where the event took place.

If you want to persist an object throughout events, you can use the `template` object that the event receives as an argument instead. This object will persist across events, as long as you're on the same template, that is.